# BigQuery - Querying Nested Fields in Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following Schema in BigQuery:

[image: Schema:]

The whole table looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `...nested`
```

[image]

I now simply want to query all rows that have a comment which is titled "Hello", and I'm breaking my head how to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM `...nested` WHERE comments.title = 'Hello'
# Error: Cannot access field title on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<title STRING, message STRING>> at [1:69]

SELECT * FROM `...nested` WHERE comments.title IN ('Hello')
# Error: Cannot access field title on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<title STRING, message STRING>> at [1:69]
```

comments.title CONTAINS "Hello" seems to be available legacy SQL, so I'm wondering what the equivalent is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dataset.nested
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(comments)
  WHERE title = 'Hello'
)
```

This returns all rows where the title of at least one comment is Hello. You can also use `LIKE` in place of the equality to look for substrings, for example. For more reading on working with arrays, see the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays).

Comment: Exactly what I needed!